# store Current Date & time in MySql Using ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, mysql, database, datetime

I want to store the current date & time which can be get by System.DateTime.`Now` in asp.net
but while storing in Mysql it gives Error of Invalid Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql stores DateTimes in the format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

So you need to do

```
System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the column type of your time column? I assume it's [DateTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html)

You should not put the datetime in it through ASP.NET but directly in your query:

```
"INSERT INTO table (dateColumn, someVar) VALUES (NOW(), \"something\")"
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use the MySQL now() function?

```
insert into mytable 
       ( id, MyDate  ) 
values ( 42, now()   )
```

If that is not possible, you will need to look into converting the client side date format into something the DB will understand.